# Numerical examples of covariant and contravariant tensor transformations

Tags: tensor-calculus

I've examined dozens of textbooks and searched the internet for numerical examples of a tensor transformation.  I remember only seeing symbolic explanations and examples in the now standard symbolism of tensors.  When it comes to the concepts of covariant and contravariant obscurities, it seems that never does any author include numerical examples showing the differences.  I am astonished why the highest level of abstraction in this branch of mathematics is presented this way.

On the other hand, a text on vector analysis is full of numerical examples, which, give the learner numerous opportunities, if so desired, to visually examine what actually happens with any vector operation that is not understood abstractly.

I would like to see one example of a covariant tensor transformation and a contravariant tensor transformation which are different, with all the numerical details at every step so that I can see exactly where the differences occur.

Comment: There are infinitely many possible examples. For starters, do you know the difference between a vector & a covector?

Comment: I was asking a question about numbers, not about physical values.  I assure you I'm not going to allow you to divert me from my straightforward mathematical question, or put me under your editing stranglehold.  Go ahead and snuff my question out.  No doubt the difference between vector and covector has importance in vectorial mathematics, but they have nothing to with my question.    As for my question being too broad, covariant and contravariant tensors are universal mathematical entities, applicable to many fields of physics.  What is so serious about a question asking only for numbers?

Comment: General tip: Edit the post to  automatically enter the review queue for a second opinion.

Comment: I'm not going to do that.

Comment: I agree that this is too broad for our format. (Generally, any question with an infinity of equally-valid answers is too broad for this format.) Moreover, I don't see the physics here ─ this is really a question for the [math.se] site.

Comment: I now understand that, E. Pisanty. I asked a Google question and the Physics StackExchange came up first. I knew nothing about Physics SE.  Where was Math SE?  I did not appreciate Qmechanic holding me hostage until I conformed to his desires. I wanted a simple answer, which anyone with a good knowledge of tensors could easily have given. If someone asked for numerical examples of cylindrical and spherical vectors, even I could have done that. That's the simple type of answer I wanted for tensors.